# c# datatable group by many columns

Tags: c#, .net

This is my old code

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
var result = (from row in InBoundtable.AsEnumerable()
              group row by row.Field<string>("Date") into grp
              select new
              {
                  AbandonCalls = grp.Sum((r) => Double.Parse(r["AvgAbandonedCalls"].ToString())),
                  Date = ((DateTime.Parse(grp.Key.ToString())) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds
              }).ToList();
```

as you see, I am making group on `Date` column.

Can I make the group on `Date` and `Slice` columns? where both of them is string value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an anonymous type using those two columns. Both columns will be part of the group's "key", so you'll have to access them separately.

```
DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

var result = (from row in new DataTable().AsEnumerable()
              group row by new
                           {
                               Date = row.Field<string>("Date"),
                               Slice = row.Field<string>("Slice")
                           }
              into grp
              select new
                     {
                         AbandonCalls = grp.Sum((r) => Double.Parse(r["AvgAbandonedCalls"].ToString())),
                         Date = ((DateTime.Parse(grp.Key.Date)) - epoch).TotalMilliseconds,
                         grp.Key.Slice
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: why did you remove the `into grp` part please?

Comment: could you please? because you have added `new {} ` which is a new syntax to me

Comment: I tried this `}into grp` and no syntax error. I am testing the results

Comment: sorry for being late, i have other problems, I will update you as soon as possible